# Anchoring TPanel so it stays on top of the form

Tags: delphi, lazarus

How can I anchor a `TPanel` so it stays at the top of the form in Lazarus?  When I do this in Delphi 7 it works fine.  It looks like the `TPanel` becomes part of the canvas and when you scroll down the `TPanel` scrolls off the screen.  The user needs to be able to click buttons on the `TPanel` no matter where it is scrolled to on the form.  Ideally I like to act like a menu on the form right below the menu for instance aligned to the top.

Here is the `FormCreate` procedure:

```
procedure TfrmTestPanel.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := nil;
  try
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    Bitmap.Width := 3000;
    Bitmap.Height := 2000; 
    imgTest.Picture.Graphic := Bitmap;
    imgTest.Width := 3000;
    imgTest.Height := 2000;
  finally 
    Bitmap.Free; 
  end;
end;
```

I have scroll bars on right and bottom of the form so the user can scroll the image either up and down or right of left.  When the user either scrolls down or to right the toolbar disappears off the screen.  I wanted the toolbar to remain on the top of form like the menu line does.  I hope this helps you understand the question.

Comment: Why a TPanel and not a TToolbar? And if a panel, why not Align := alTop? And *scroll down* in *what* exactly? Please keep in mind that we can't see your screen from where we're sitting, and we can't read your mind; the only information we have available is what you provide in your question. If you want us to help you, please provide the **specific** details about what you're asking.

Comment: procedure TfrmTestPanel.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := nil;
  try
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    Bitmap.Width := 3000;
    Bitmap.Height := 2000;
    imgTest.Picture.Graphic := Bitmap;
    imgTest.Width := 3000;
    imgTest.Height := 2000;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add details, instead of burying them in comments. Putting the details in the post makes them available, and you can properly format the code so it's readable. You can also explain how a bitmap (which had nothing to do with the question you asked) suddenly is relevant.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I dont see a panel in your code

Comment: I presume that code is an attempt for us to have a form with scrollbars. We are also expected to turn Autoscroll on and put an altop aligned panel and then we have a reproduction case.

Comment: Anyway, a panel or a toolbar won't help you. What you need to do is to alter the client area of the form. Like a menu, it's part of non-client area.

Comment: BTW, of course it wouldn't work with D7 too, I guess you have to look deeper your D7 code.

Comment: I used a TToolbar instead and got the same result in scrolling off the form's viewable area.  I didn't test this in Delphi 7.  I had used the example   GraphEx which used a TPanel in Delphi 7.

Comment: @keterpstra - GraphEx has a scrollbox. You can put it anywhere you like.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply put your image into a `ScrollBox` instead placing it directly onto the form.

This way you will be able to scroll the image using ScrollBox ScrollBars without moving any other controls on your form as you do by using form ScrollBars.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for the image.  This is first success I had with not having the TPanel not move off the form window.  I'll have test it more to make the canvas work so I can draw lines on it.

Comment: Note that you haven't answered the question.

Comment: Given that the question asks "How can I anchor a TPanel so it stays at the top of the form" and "wanted the toolbar to remain on the top of form like the menu line does". This is a perfectly actionable answer. It remains for @keterpstra_mwu to accept the answer if it actually does solve his problem. _It seems to me Sertac's impertinent comment is an attempt to justify his very similar answer (nearly 8h after this) which first claims it's not possible, then explains how another app achieved the desired effect using the very technique described in this answer._

Comment: Who do you think cares how does it seem to you or what you find impertinent @Craig?

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. Scroll bars of a form are [standard scroll bars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787527(v=vs.85).aspx#standard_scroll_bars) of the form's window, hence they scroll the entire client area. Whatever control you put on the form is in the client area, no anchoring will change this. So it will scroll with the rest of the client area.

A menu is different, it is part of non-client area. You can't mimic a window menu's position with standard controls.

In comments to the question you mention you have tested with the GraphEx demo program. GraphEx has a client area aligned scroll box under the top aligned panels. A scroll box is a window with scroll bars that you can place on a form. Lazarus have it on the "additional" palette. You can use the same layout with Lazarus with the GraphEx demo by using a scroll box.